# Why do I need a "high" reputation to comment?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I wondered why 50 reputation points are required to comment on an answer.
Being new on this kind of side, it seems to me, that contributing to questions, could be encouraged by allowing comments earlier.

In my case, I have seen multiple answers, to different questions, where I would have liked to expand on certain aspects. It felt like I could not provide a good enough (full) answer, but could add useful information to someone else’s … Which was not possible.

Comment: Note that it's not as bad as it seems.  Once you've earned 200 reputation on *any* SE site, you'll automatically get 100 points on *all* other sites. You'll never experience this annoyance again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [lengthy post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/461068) that goes over this in more detail, but essentially, it's to prevent people from commenting spam links, gibberish, trolling/abuse, and generally unwanted noise like "thanks, this worked" or "yes, I agree". Comments are for precisely what you describe - asking for clarification, or suggesting improvements - but unfortunately a little gatekeeping is needed to help ensure that that's *all* they're used for.

This place isn't as active as it used to be, but your two answers so far have been well-written, so I'm sure that if you keep contributing answers of that calibre, you'll hit that 50-rep barrier in no time.